# what is the difference between kernel and system software?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I really quite confused with the kernel and system software are they same, metaphors, or different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel is one component of the operating system which connects the other components to each other and to the hardware. [The Source of All Truth and Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) has extensive articles which explain how all the bits work, as a quick Google search would have shown you.